# How to pass an array of integers to a function as an argument and modify the content?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to modify an array of integers through a function, but the array maintains its original values. I tried to accesses its values to modify it:

This produces an error:

```
*array[i] = *array[i] * *array[i];
```

This example runs the program but the array will be modified:

```
int main() {
    int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6};
    int size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(int); 
    square_array_values(&array, size);
}

void square_array_values(int *array, int size) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("Array[%d]: %d.\n", i, array[i]);
        array[i] = array[i] * array[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify,  do you want to modify the content of your array, or do you not want to modify it ? Your 2. code snippet is fine if you want to modify the content of the array - that's exactly what it does. You should pass `array` to square_array_values() though, not `&array`

Comment: The erroneous single line you show is not in the other code snippet you show, how are those two related? Also, when asking questions about build errors, include the complete and unedited error output, in full (inclusive informational notes). Also please try to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us, including prototype declarations and header files included.

Comment: *but the array maintains its original values*?  One cannot tell this from the code posted, and I'm willing to bet that the array **is** indeed modified, although its address is passed incorrectly.

Comment: You pass `&array`, but your parameter is `int *array`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Passing `&array` is indeed an error, but it does not explain the OP's observation.  It should have no effect at all.

Comment: Thank you all, its my bad.. I forgot to check the array afterwards.

Comment: *but the array maintains its original values?*. You are not printing the values after it is changed. How would you know. you printed the values before changing them

Comment: after chqrlie's comment, I just added a printf() loop and it is modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is late to the answer party - I hope it gives you some ideas about how to add prints to your code to help show what is going on.

Consider the output from the following program.  There are several ways you could approach this, this is just one possibility.  All of the earlier answers are solid and should give you some good ideas.

You're going to need to build up your mental model of how memory allocation works in C so you can predict what the compiler will do.  I find that printing out the values of variables AND their addresses is often helpful.  You would benefit from sketching a "memory map" with paper and pencil so you know which variables are referencing which storage.

### Foo.c output

```
$ gcc Foo.c
$ ./a.out
hello from main(), size=7
array1= 0x7ffc36ef7da0, &(array1)= 0x7ffc36ef7da0
  Note that &(array1[0]) equals both the value of array1 and &(array1), above.
  Also, each subsequent address of array1's elements is sizeof(int) = 4 more
  than the previous element, e.g. &(array[N]) = &(array[N-1]) + 4)
   ---- before, array1 ----
   array1[0]=1            |  0x7ffc36ef7da0
   array1[1]=2            |  0x7ffc36ef7da4
   array1[2]=3            |  0x7ffc36ef7da8
   array1[3]=4            |  0x7ffc36ef7dac
   array1[4]=5            |  0x7ffc36ef7db0
   array1[5]=6            |  0x7ffc36ef7db4
   array1[6]=7            |  0x7ffc36ef7db8
array2=       0x400b0d, &(array2)= 0x7ffc36ef7d98
   We haven't allocated array2 yet, so no contents to print out.
   In fact, we Really Shouldn't be printing what array2 'points' to at all,
   but (when it doesn't blow up on an address violation) it does kind of
  emphasize the nature of uninitialized values.
   ---- before (an uninitialzed array2) ----
   array2[0]=29590344     |        0x400b0d
   array2[1]=1978349896   |        0x400b11
   array2[2]=-998029078   |        0x400b15
   array2[3]=1096637192   |        0x400b19
   array2[4]=1096630620   |        0x400b1d
   array2[5]=-1017167522  |        0x400b21
   array2[6]=254699152    |        0x400b25

Hello from square_array_values(), size=7
array= 0x7ffc36ef7da0, &(array)= 0x7ffc36ef7d58
   Note that the Value of our array param here is the same as main()'s array1, above.
   But the Address of our array param here, &(array) is Different than the main()'s &(array1), above.
before malloc, result=          (nil), &(result)= 0x7ffc36ef7d70
 after malloc, result=      0x2082010, &(result)= 0x7ffc36ef7d70
   Note that none of the values above for main()'s array2 match what we have
   here for square_array_value()'s variable result.
   They value of main()'s array2 Will match our value of result after we return (see below).
So, let's square some values...
   array[0]=1   | result[0]=1
   array[1]=2   | result[1]=4
   array[2]=3   | result[2]=9
   array[3]=4   | result[3]=16
   array[4]=5   | result[4]=25
   array[5]=6   | result[5]=36
   array[6]=7   | result[6]=49
Goodbye from square_array_values(), returning result=0x2082010
back in main().
array1= 0x7ffc36ef7da0, &(array)= 0x7ffc36ef7da0
   Note we have no differences from 'before.array1', above.
   All of array1's values and addresses are the same.
   ---- after ----
   array1[0]=1            |  0x7ffc36ef7da0
   array1[1]=2            |  0x7ffc36ef7da4
   array1[2]=3            |  0x7ffc36ef7da8
   array1[3]=4            |  0x7ffc36ef7dac
   array1[4]=5            |  0x7ffc36ef7db0
   array1[5]=6            |  0x7ffc36ef7db4
   array1[6]=7            |  0x7ffc36ef7db8
array2=      0x2082010, &(array2)= 0x7ffc36ef7d98
   array2, however, is significantly different from 'before.array2', above.
   array2 is now pointing to nicely initialized memory - thank you, square_array_values().
   ---- after (now array2 is initialized) ----
   array2[0]=1            |       0x2082010
   array2[1]=4            |       0x2082014
   array2[2]=9            |       0x2082018
   array2[3]=16           |       0x208201c
   array2[4]=25           |       0x2082020
   array2[5]=36           |       0x2082024
   array2[6]=49           |       0x2082028
main(): done.
$
```

### Foo.c

I stuffed a fairly crazy number of printf()s into your original code, and a helper function to dump out a given array.  Normally I wouldn't go this far in my own development, but I wanted it to be easier for you to "imagine" what your program's memory locations look like at run time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int *square_array_values(int *array, int size); /* modified return type */
void dump_array( char *msg, char *label, int *array, int size );

int main() {
    /* typo? double 4's ? */
    /* ORIGINAL: int array1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6}; */
    int array1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    int size = sizeof(array1)/sizeof(int);
    int *array2; /* we can let square_array_values() assign the result array */
    /* Or you could declare another array up here and pass that in */

    printf("hello from main(), size=%d\n", size );
    printf("array1=%15p, &(array1)=%15p\n", array1, &array1 );
    printf("  Note that &(array1[0]) equals both the value of array1 and &(array1), above.\n");
    printf("  Also, each subsequent address of array1's elements is sizeof(int) = %ld more\n", sizeof(int) );
    printf("  than the previous element, e.g. &(array[N]) = &(array[N-1]) + %ld)\n", sizeof(int) );
    dump_array( "before, array1", "array1", array1, size );
    printf("array2=%15p, &(array2)=%15p\n", array2, &array2 );
    printf("   We haven't allocated array2 yet, so no contents to print out.\n");
    printf("   In fact, we Really Shouldn't be printing what array2 'points' to at all,\n");
    printf("   but (when it doesn't blow up on an address violation) it does kind of\n");
    printf( "  emphasize the nature of uninitialized values.\n");
    dump_array( "before (an uninitialzed array2)", "array2", array2, size );


    /* original - try running it this way too...
     *     void square_array_values( &array1, size);
     */
    array2 = square_array_values(array1, size);
    printf("back in main().\n");

    printf("array1=%15p, &(array)=%15p\n", array1, &array1 );
    printf("   Note we have no differences from 'before.array1', above.\n");
    printf("   All of array1's values and addresses are the same.\n");
    dump_array( "after", "array1", array1, size );

    printf("array2=%15p, &(array2)=%15p\n", array2, &array2 );
    printf("   array2, however, is significantly different from 'before.array2', above.\n");
    printf("   array2 is now pointing to nicely initialized memory - thank you, square_array_values().\n");
    dump_array( "after (now array2 is initialized)", "array2", array2, size );

    free( array2 );
    printf("main(): done.\n");
}

int *square_array_values(int *array, int size) {
    int i;
    int *result;
    printf("\nHello from square_array_values(), size=%d\n", size );
    printf("array=%15p, &(array)=%15p\n", array, &array );
    printf("   Note that the Value of our array param here is the same as main()'s array1, above.\n");
    printf("   But the Address of our array param here, &(array) is Different than the main()'s &(array1), above.\n");
    printf("before malloc, result=%15p, &(result)=%15p\n", result, &result);
    result = malloc( sizeof(int) * size );
    printf(" after malloc, result=%15p, &(result)=%15p\n", result, &result);
    printf("   Note that none of the values above for main()'s array2 match what we have\n");
    printf("   here for square_array_value()'s variable result.\n");
    printf("   They value of main()'s array2 Will match our value of result after we return (see below).\n");
    printf("So, let's square some values...\n");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        result[i] = array[i] * array[i];
        printf("   array[%d]=%d   | result[%d]=%d\n", i, array[i], i, result[i] );
    }
    printf("Goodbye from square_array_values(), returning result=%p\n", result);
    return result;
}

void dump_array( char *msg, char *label, int *array, int size ) {
   printf("   ---- %s ----\n", msg );
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("   %s[%d]=%-12d | %15p\n", label, i, array[i], &(array[i]) );
    }
}
```

Comment: It took me a while to go through your code and it was very helpful in understanding memory allocations in C, so thank you very much.

Comment: @user3419211: I'm glad it was helpful.  It took me a while to wrap my head around pointers in my early days with C, but it was super helpful to get down to that level.  Thanks for the kind words and happy coding. :-)

Answer (score 3):

For arrays, the array name itself is the base address of the array. So for your example, you just need to send that(`array`) to the function.

As sending arrays to some function decays them to a pointer, it would work perfectly with your implementation of `square_array_values()`

Change to

```
square_array_values(array, size);
```

---

I don't always say this, but since I am in a good mood.

Always do

```
int main(void)
```

and not

```
int main()
```

`int main()` means that `main` can accept any number of arguments.

Comment: This is true, but it does not explain why the array would stay unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

You should not pass the address of the array, tha array itself is converted to a pointer. Just change this

```
square_array_values(&array, size);
```

to

```
square_array_values(array, size);
```

without the address of `&` operator, with it the pointer you passed has type `int (*)[]` instead of `int *` which is what you need.

Also, you could enable compiler warnings and an *incompatible type* warning should be issued.

Comment: This is true, but it does not explain why the array would stay unchanged.

Comment: True again, but still no explanation for the OP's observation.  Passing `&array` or `array` makes no difference, the function receives the same value and its definition implies the argument is treated as a regular `int *`.

Answer (score 2):

Passing the address of the array as `&array` is incorrect, you should just pass the array directly, The compiler will automatically pass a pointer to its first element.  This is called *decaying*.

You observe that the array remains unchanged, but think again: you print the contents of each array element **before** modifying it.  Change the code to this:

```
void square_array_values(int *array, int size) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i] * array[i];
        printf("Array[%d]: %d.\n", i, array[i]);
    }
}
```

Follow these steps:

- Recompile and verify that the array is indeed modified.
- Then move the definition of `square_array_values` before `main` and compile again: you should get a warning about the type mismatch.
- Finally fix the calling site as `square_array_values(array, size);`, and `return 0;` from `main`.